# what is the different ways to require FB like permissions?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Can someone explain what is the difference in getting permissions in one of the two:

1) via code, on first Fb login:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.facebook_login);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    // authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_status"));
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info",
            "user_birthday", "user_interests", "user_likes", "email",
            "user_location", "publish_actions"));
```

2) via Facebook developer page:

if there is none, what is the duplication?
`App Details --> Configure App Center Permissions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (1), i.e. in code, you can choose at execution time which permissions to ask for. This means you can, for example, initially ask for just public_profile, and then later when the user wants to share something you can ask again for "publish_actions".

In (2), you are setting which permissions the user will grant if they start playing via the app centre (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/yourgame). In this case the set of permissions you choose will be shown to the user in the app center before they start your game. When they press Play in the app centre they are granting the chosen permissions, so you don't need to call a login method from within your code.

These two sets of permissions can be different.

Comment: what do you mean `before they start your game.` I'm talking about android app in both case. not FB game-app

Comment: App Center is a portal on Facebook web, iOS and Android where people can view games that developers choose to list there. The app centre permissions are the permissions that are displayed on the listing for your app (if you choose to list it there). https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/09/introducing-the-app-center/